# Input field that gets cleared on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

What would be the best way to clear an input field on $.(document).ready()?

What I'd like to happen is when the user reloads or navigates away and navigates back to the page, the input field clears when the DOM is ready.

I've tried innerHTML and value="" but those don't seem to work.

Comment: This should be the default behavior, right? When a page loads if you are not assigning some value in HTML of the textbox then there won't be any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.(document).ready(function{
$("input:text").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a jQuery representation of a DOM element, use the val method:

```
$('input:text').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://api.jquery.com/val/?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value should work, but don't use `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` .
Depending on the browser those events may not fire if the user navigates using back/forward.

Just put it somewhere at the end of the document, beyond the last input-element.